# Display:flex stretching percentage width images

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox, display

I am trying to code a responsive icon-based menu bar. I am using display:flex to do this but the issue I am having is that the images keep wanting to stretch or squish horizontally when the page is scaled up or down. If they would just move relative to each other and scale uniformally that would be the better solution.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                #A {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-around;
                }

                .B {
                    width: 15%
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="A">
                <img class="B" src="http://tinyurl.com/h9zm7bp">
                <img class="B" src="http://tinyurl.com/h9zm7bp">
                <img class="B" src="http://tinyurl.com/h9zm7bp">
                <img class="B" src="http://tinyurl.com/h9zm7bp">
                <img class="B" src="http://tinyurl.com/h9zm7bp">
            </div>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: with display flex you need to give B a px width  , also add flex-wrap:wrap;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have `display: flex` distribute the space without squishing images, you can convert the images into, say, `<div>`s and set the images as backgrounds with `background-size: contain`.

```
<!--- ... --->
<style>
    #A {

    }

    .B {
       width: 15%;
       background-image: url("http://tinyurl.com/h9zm7bp");
       background-size: contain;
    }
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<div id="A">
   <div class="B"></div>
   <div class="B"></div>
   <div class="B"></div>
</div>
```

Also, for some reason, setting a %-based height works:

```
   #A {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .B {
        width: 15%;
        height: 1%; /* literally any % works here for some reason */
    }
```

Here's a CodePen to demonstrate: 
http://codepen.io/milaniliev/pen/eZgZJz

I have no explanation for *why* that works. It seems the actual height % is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the help for some reason when I copy the code over to my text editor the solution doesn't work but instead shrinks the height of the images.

Comment: Huh. You're right, it appears CodePen is messing with it in some way, although Chrome's inspector doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: yeah I have messed with the width in the inspector and everything is honky dory but as soon as I make those changes live it craps out and breaks

Comment: I see the problem! Your code does not begin with `<!doctype html>` and an opening `<html>` tag. Try those.

Comment: Just tried it and that didn't effect it. I was going to punch myself if that worked.

Comment: Odd, I just tried it again in a plain HTML file in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, and they all worked fine.

Comment: Here's a Gist with the exact code I used, just in case:

https://gist.github.com/milaniliev/a76887895579b7d40a5b

Comment: I copied over your code to my text editor and apparently that did the trick! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#A {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.B {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: That works in part.What I really need is the icons to shrink down when the page is condensed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use px instead of % and use the following code

```
#A {
 overflow: auto;
}
#B {
 float: left;
 width: (in px);
}
```

Comment: Float shift the images towards left and px make them of fixed sized. now as the screen shrinks. the images of fixed sized find congestion so move down easily.

Comment: This does make the images not squish, but it seems the question is asking how to make them *resize* as the page resizes.